# how to auto increment an input name in html and save in database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, auto-increment

I have a table named ***positions***. This table has the list of the different positions that the admin has added in the *listOfPositions.php* like President, Vice-President, etc. After adding different positions, he can now add the different people under that position. And that's where my problem is. How will I have an auto increment input name for the names of the people depending on how many positions it has in the table ***positions*** ?

I tried using javascript, but it increments only in the html and not reflecting to the php when I try to save. My current code where the adding of the names of different persons depending on the position is the ff:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
<form action="post_officers.php" method="post"><br>
<center><select name="year">

<?php

    for($i=date('Y'); $i>1999; $i=$i-2) {
    $selected = '';
    $year2 = $i-2;
        if ($year == $i) $selected = ' selected="selected"';
        echo ('<option value="'.$year2. "-" . $i .'" '.$selected.'> '.$year2.'-'.$i.'</option>'."\n");
}
?>
</select></center>


    <?php 
    include_once('dbcontroller.php');   
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM positions ORDER BY pos_id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    /* assign an onchange event handler */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $position = $row['position'];
    ?>
        <br><br>
        <table id="options-table">                  
            <tr>
                <td><input type="file" name="file" /></td>    
                <td><input type="hidden" name="position" /><?php echo $position; ?></td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
            </tr>                  

        </table>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SAVE"/>
</form>         
<script>            
                $("input[name='file']").each(function(ind) {
                        $(this).attr(ind + 1);
                });

                $("input[name='position']").each(function(ind) {
                        $(this).attr(ind + 1);
                });

                $("input[name='name']").each(function(ind) {
                        $(this).attr(ind + 1);
                     });


</script>
```

And this is my php code:

```
<?php
   include ('dbcontroller.php');
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
            $year = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['year']);

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM officers WHERE year = '$year'");
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($num_rows>0){
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Year already exists.'); window.location.href='create_alumni_officers.php';</script>";
        }
        else {
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++) {
                        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['name'.$i]);
                        $position = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['position'.$i]);

                        $file=(rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file'.$i]['name']);
                        $type=($_FILES['file'.$i]['type']);
                        $size=$_FILES['file'.$i]['size'];
                        $loc=($_FILES['file'.$i]['tmp_name']);

                        $new_size=$size/1024; // file size in KB

                        // make file name in lower case
                         $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
                         // make file name in lower case

                         $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

                  if(move_uploaded_file($loc, '../officers-avatars/'.$final_file)) {
                                          echo "Page is loading, please wait...";
                      $result = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO officers VALUES (id, '$year', '$position', '$name', '$final_file', '$new_size', '$type')")
                      or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                      echo ("<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='alumni_officers.php';</script>");
                    }
            }

        }
   }


?>
```

And this doesn't work at all. Any help? I hope you guys understood what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: I don't understand what you really want here but could probably help.

Comment: yeah i know. @Jeff how will i have this *<input type="text" name="name1">* without 1 next to the name since i want it to be auto increment?

Comment: It gets pretty messy to switch contexts between php, html, and javascript. Just as a suggestion toy might want to consider creating php objects for the html output.  Nevertheless, I get the feeling what you want is the input tag to contain the name attribute that corresponds with an auto incremented number retrieved from the positions table. Confirm I have an accurate understanding please.

Comment: You* not toy darn swipe type

Comment: Yes you're right, that's what I want to do but I'm not sure how? @Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the best way to do it:**

```
<?php 
    include_once('dbcontroller.php');   
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM positions ORDER BY pos_id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    /* assign an onchange event handler */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $position = $row['position'];
    ?>
<table id="options-table">                  
            <tr>
                <td><input type="file" name="file[<?php echo $position; ?>]" /></td>    
                <td><input type="hidden" name="position[<?php echo $position; ?>]" value="<?php echo $position; ?>" /><?php echo $position; ?></td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="name[<?php echo $position; ?>]" /></td>
            </tr>                  

        </table>
 <?php 
    }
    ?>
```

You don't need the javascript to change input attributes. Remove it.

In php use foreach loop like:

If you are still getting errors I will need to see the output of `print_r($_POST);`

```
<?php 
$files = $_FILES['file'];
$positions = $_POST['position']; //use this for the foreach loop because it will always have a value
$names = $_POST['name'];

foreach($positions as $key=>$position){
  $file = @$files[$key];
  $name= @$names[$key];
  //Do your magic  for each user here
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$name);
    $position = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$position);

    $filename = rand(1000,100000)."-".$file['name'];
    $type = $file['type'];
    $size = $file['size'];
    $loc = $file['tmp_name'];

    $new_size=$size/1024; // file size in KB

    // make file name in lower case
     $new_file_name = strtolower($filename);
     // make file name in lower case

     $final_file = str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

    if(move_uploaded_file($loc, '../officers-avatars/'.$final_file)) {
                          echo "Page is loading, please wait...";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO officers VALUES (id, '$year', '$position', '$name', '$final_file', '$new_size', '$type')")
      or die(mysqli_error($conn));
      echo ("<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='alumni_officers.php';</script>");
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: I will try this one. Thank you.

Comment: Note: For the position input in html you need to add a value to it. I am going to edit it.

Comment: Editing.. the answer. Sorry I thought you could pick it up from that code.

Comment: I just saw  your edit, but I was able to do it already. But I still have an undefined index. and these undefined index were the positions like President, etc.

Comment: and that index comes from this line `$file = $files[$key];`

Comment: I am sorry the $files variable has to be like this `$files = $_FILES['file'];` I am going to edit the answer.

Comment: It's really okay, you're a big help. But I already did that and it's still the same.

Comment: I missed that "@" . Uggh. Sorry, thank you so much for the help! One more thing, why use "@" ?

Comment: I thought everything's working, but I just realized that they are not inserting in the database. I wonder why?

Comment: Your sql has error 'id' shouldn't be there like that. Utilize this method `INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);` that way you can start from 'year' and ignore the 'id' if it's set to auto increment in your data base. Look here -> [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Comment: I was able to do it, it's working now. Thanks so much for your big help! I edited your answer with the one that worked for me. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

As I indicated in the contents,  removing context switches miss fide will greatly increase the readability of your code. I'll illustrate below a bit as well as answer the question.

To get what you're after, you could do this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$position = $row['position'];
?>
    <br><br>
    <table id="options-table">                  
        <tr>
            <td><input type="file" name="file" /></td>    
            <td><input type="hidden" name="position" /><?php echo $position; ?></td>
             <td><input type="text" name="name<?php echo $position; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>                  

    </table>
<?php 
}
```

However, to illustrate a small example of removing these contextual switches mid code, see below and pardon but this is air code, if you want a more specific example, just ask.

Let's say you often use the  tag thoughout your site in forms. You could drop out of php each time and just write out the straight html. Or, you could create a class, or even a simple function for the html output thusly:

```
    Function opt($int, $parms = '') {
Return '<Option '.$parms.'>'. $int.'</option>';
}
```

Now your code would look more like this:

```
While ($r =mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {
Extract ($r); // learn this,  no sense assigning them 1 by 1
$options .= opt($databaseobject, 'name="foo" value="'. $databaseobjectid.'"');
}
Echo $options;
```

Comment: i'm sorry but it's confusing for me.

Comment: What part is confusing? I'll try to clarify.